# Describe http request/reply in json

Tags: json, http

I have a case where I have to serialize a N number of http requests, perform the requests in parallel, and describe the response in the same json. To do this in json is pretty easy obviously, I could do something like:

```
[
  {
    "request": {
      "uri": "http://something",
      "headers": [
        {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
      ],
      "body": ".. snip .. you get the idea",
      "other-stuff": ""
    },
    "response": {
      // something along the lines of the request structure to be filled in after the request completed
    }
  },
  // second request/response here, and so on.
]
```

But while I could make this format up myself, I feel this problem is (very) likely solved before, and there should be some sort of json standard floating around that does this. Can't find it though. Have you encountered this somewhere?

Comment: What do you mean by "something along the lines of the request structure to be filled in"? Do you mean "expected response body"? Is this what you want: read JSON array, extract multiple request objects and send them in parallel, finally compare the real response to the response object in JSON?

Comment: Yes, the response body. It'll be largely the same as the request structure because a response also has headers, the uri, and so on. That's why I said "something along the lines of..". I don't know what you mean by "compare the real response". I don't know the real response. The response section is where I'll add the response once it comes back.

Comment: Ah, I thought you want to describe HTTP request/response test case. But it appears what you need is serialize request/response data. There are several JSON standard to describe HTTP request & response, such as JSON Hyper-Schema, JSON API etc. but none of them is exactly what you need...